# Vue.js 2, WATCH "Error in callback for watcher "yourAccountsState": "ReferenceError: value is not defined""

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following WATCH property watching my v-model data (this is for checkboxes and I'm using bootstrap-vue).

I think my mistake is in how I'm setting the value in either the WATCH or how it is being called in my store?  (is it an issue because an array is being sent over?)

I can console inside the WATCH, but when I dispatch, then I get the error.

Here is the checkbox markup:

```
<b-form-group label="Using sub-components:">
        <b-form-checkbox-group id="checkboxes1" name="flavour1" v-model="yourAccounts">
            <b-form-checkbox :value="test.value" class="card" v-for="test in filteredList" :key="bank.text">
                {{ test.text }}
            </b-form-checkbox>
        </b-form-checkbox-group>
</b-form-group>
```

the computer property:

```
computed: {
    yourAccountsState: {
        get() {
            // console.log(this.yourAccounts);
            return this.yourAccounts
        },
    }
},
watch: {
    yourAccountsState(value) {
        this.$store.dispatch('setTestAccounts', value);

        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

In my store.js I have the following imported from a modules

```
        const state = {
    TestAccounts: []
}

const mutations = {
    // from v-modal on selected accounts page
    SET_SELECTED_TESTS (state, testAccount) {
        state.TestAccounts = testAccount
    }
}

const actions = {
    setTestAccounts: ({commit}) => {
        commit('SET_SELECTED_TESTS', value);
    }
}

const getters = {
    yourAccounts: state => {
        return state.TestAccounts
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't look like you're calling `yourAccountsState.set()` anywhere.

Comment: @Julxzs That is correct because it should be sent to the Store.  OOO, should I be using a 'watcher' instead?? So a watcher to do the dispatch?

Comment: Yeah, I think so

Comment: Is `setTestAccounts` in your setter defined somewhere or are you missing quotes around it?

Comment: @Julxzs I updated to a WATCH, finally some progress, but my value is undefined and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @sliptype good catch, updated as well

Comment: In your computed it should be `return this.$store.yourAccounts` no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `v-model`, you need to give Vue a setter, because `v-model` is a shorthand method which executes `v-bind` and `v-on` behind the scenes.

If you don't provide a setter, the watcher won't be triggered the way you want. 
And you have to make sure, that the property you assign to `v-model` is an array, so that the values can be stored as described in the bootstrap-vue docs.

Comment: if I do "commit" instead of dispatch, so directly to the mutation instead fo the action, it works fine.  I think something is wrong with how my action is now set up

Comment: Yes, in your Action you don't pass the payload. The function definition has to be

    `setTestAccounts: ({commit}, value) => {
        commit('SET_SELECTED_TESTS', value);
    }`

Comment: silly mistake, wasn't even registering that was it.  Thanks! Good to go

Comment: For me, the data variable I was binding an array to needed to be declared as "[ ]" instead of "null", then I got rid of this error. Thanks!